# C++ floating point accuracy in while loops

Tags: c++, floating-point, while-loop, floating-accuracy

I am trying to count the amount of dollar and coin denominations in a grand total by using a series of while loops. When I get down to the coins however, I am off by a penny. When I enter say 99.95, I get the output 3 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, and 4 pennies. I've narrowed the problem down to a floating point accuracy issue. However all the solutions I've researched haven't been applicable in my situation. Any pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
   float amount;
   cout<<"enter amount" << endl;
   cin>>amount;
   int pennies=0, nickels=0, dimes=0, quarters=0, ones=0, fives=0, 
tens=0, 
twenties=0, fifties=0, hundreds=0;

   while (amount >= 100) 
   {
      hundreds = hundreds +1;
      amount = amount - 100;

   }
   while (amount >= 50)
   {
      fifties = fifties +1;
      amount = amount - 50;

   }
   while (amount >= 20)
   {
      twenties = twenties +1;
      amount = amount - 20;

   }
   while (amount >= 10)
   {
      tens = tens +1;
      amount = amount - 10;

   }
   while (amount >= 5)
   {
      fives = fives +1;
      amount = amount - 5;

   }
   while (amount >= 1)
   {
      ones = ones +1;
      amount = amount - 1;

   }
   while (amount >= .25)
   {
      quarters = quarters +1;
      amount = amount - .25;

   }
   while (amount >= .10)
   {
      dimes = dimes +1;
      amount = amount - .10;

   }
   while (amount >= .05)
   {
      nickels = nickels +1;
      amount = amount - .05;

   }
   while (amount >= .01)
   {
      pennies = pennies +1;
      amount = amount - .01;

   }


   cout<<endl<<"pennies:"<< pennies;
   cout<<endl<<"nickels:"<<nickels;
   cout<<endl<<"dimes:"<<dimes;
   cout<<endl<<"quarters:"<<quarters;
   cout<<endl<<"ones:"<<ones;
   cout<<endl<<"fives:"<<fives;
   cout<<endl<<"tens:"<<tens;
   cout<<endl<<"twenties:"<<twenties;
   cout<<endl<<"fifties:"<<fifties;
   cout<<endl<<"hundreds:"<<hundreds<<endl;







return 0;
}
```

Comment: dont use a float for amount. use an integer number of pennies.

Comment: Your last comparison to `amount >= 0.01` will cause a problem if amount is imprecisely represented as 0.0099999999.  At the end of your calculation, you could check if amount leftover is > half a cent, then add one to your answer.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.ualberta.ca/~kbeach/phys420_580_2010/docs/ACM-Goldberg.pdf)

Comment: Can we find the professors who keep assigning this ridiculous homework exercise and beat them until they agree to stop? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128584/small-bug-in-my-short-c-code-why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654331/rounding-up-with-pennies-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441488/calculating-the-dollars-right-in-the-money-change-program-c etc, etc, etc...

Comment: @StephenCanon Perhaps one or two of them do it so the students get some first-hand experience with floating-point problems. I can imagine that's more instructive than just parroting "Don't use floating point for money".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use floating point in cases where you need exact values. 99.95 can't be exactly represented in a float or double, a bit like 1/3 can't be exactly represented using a finite number of normal decimal digits.

As Doug T. suggested, you can use an integer to hold the number of pennies. When the user types 123.45, read it as two integers, and then store it as 12345 pennies, not as 123.45 dollars.

In this case, you can also try to change your last `while (amount >= .01)` to something like `while (amount >= .005)`. It's not a solution that can be generally recommended, and if this is a real-life bank application you really should avoid it, but it will help against at least some of the errors.

Comment: What do propose I do then? How can I take a money number from the user without using float or double? Also when I subtract .25, .1, etc. won't my amount variable end in an unrepresentable number?

Comment: Given the string `199.95` can you produce the integer `19995`?

Comment: @Yakk: sscanf("%d.%d", "199.15", &dollars, &cents); pennies = 100*dollars + cents;

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I think it was a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Dave: I always answer those.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Parsing like that fails to detect some errors or to handle situations where there may be a different number of digits after the decimal point, as when quoting stock prices or currency exchange rates.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy inefficient.  Just do `int x=19995;` -- producing `19995` given the string `199.95` is no harder than just producing `19995`.  Plus, you are off by 80 cents.  ;)  But yes, I was aiming the question @Ktmock13 who didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using fixed-point values in this case, not floating-point.

Although people think of money in terms of dollars, which aren't exact, money is measured in cents, which are exact. Just count the number of cents, divide by 100 to get the dollar amount, and take the modulus to get the cent amount. Floating-point is not the proper tool in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Binary floating point numbers cannot, in general, represent fractional decimal values, even if the total number of decimals is small. For example, `0.1` cannot be represented exactly.

To deal with exact values different approaches exist which all amount to using a different base than `2`. Depending on tge specific needs the approaches are more or less involved. The easieast approach for your case is to use a fixed precision instead of a variable precision. To compute with fixed precision you'd just use an integer which represents the value you actually want multiplied by a suitable power of `10`. Depending on the amount of computations you do you can either package the logic into a class or distribute it throughout the code. In a "real" application I'd package it into a class, in an assignment (homework, interview, etc.) I'd probably just apply the logic directly to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code, I used TJD's advice and instead of using .01 i used .0099 instead. For my problem that seems to work, thanks guys!

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
   float amount;
   cout<<"enter amount" << endl;
   cin>>amount;
   int pennies=0, nickels=0, dimes=0, quarters=0, ones=0, fives=0, 
tens=0, 
twenties=0, fifties=0, hundreds=0;
   float p = .0099, n = .0499, d = .099, q = .2499;   
   while (amount >= 100) 
   {
      hundreds = hundreds +1;
      amount = amount - 100;

   }
   while (amount >= 50)
   {
      fifties = fifties +1;
      amount = amount - 50;

   }
   while (amount >= 20)
   {
      twenties = twenties +1;
      amount = amount - 20;

   }
   while (amount >= 10)
   {
      tens = tens +1;
      amount = amount - 10;

   }
   while (amount >= 5)
   {
      fives = fives +1;
      amount = amount - 5;

   }
   while (amount >= 1)
   {
      ones = ones +1;
      amount = amount - 1;

   }
   while (amount >= q)
   {
      quarters = quarters +1;
      amount = amount - q;

   }
   while (amount >= d)
   {
      dimes = dimes +1;
      amount = amount - d;

   }
   while (amount >= n)
   {
      nickels = nickels +1;
      amount = amount - n;

   }
   while (amount >= p)
   {
      pennies = pennies +1;
      amount = amount - p;

   }


   cout<<endl<<"pennies:"<< pennies;
   cout<<endl<<"nickels:"<<nickels;
   cout<<endl<<"dimes:"<<dimes;
   cout<<endl<<"quarters:"<<quarters;
   cout<<endl<<"ones:"<<ones;
   cout<<endl<<"fives:"<<fives;
   cout<<endl<<"tens:"<<tens;
   cout<<endl<<"twenties:"<<twenties;
   cout<<endl<<"fifties:"<<fifties;
   cout<<endl<<"hundreds:"<<hundreds<<endl;







return 0;
}
```